# Why isn't our Twitter account tweeting?

Tags: bug, status-completed

So we have a Twitter account, [@StackArduino](http://twitter.com/StackArduino). However, it hasn't tweeted, has no profile picture, and isn't linked to anywhere. Why is this, and can the account be "activated"?

Comment: There are more upvotes on this question, than there are followers on the Twitter account :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, that would ultimately be an oopsie on our end. We had it configured properly (yay), but almost immediately something happened to un-configure it (ugh), and we didn't re-configure it (d'oh). It has just been fixed, and should be working soon!